# Jump command in shell

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am very new to shell scripting, and my question is very simple.
in the below code does ":go_start" excutes until ":setpython" and does the "setpython" executes until the call function at the end of the code.

```js
if X == "somthing" goto setpython
:go_start
rem ------------------------------Debug--------------------------------------
IF "%debug%"=="1" (
ECHO SiL Debug on 
SET DEBUG_SOFTCAR=1 
) ELSE (
ECHO SiL Debug off 
SET DEBUG_SOFTCAR=0 
)
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF "%env%"=="S" ( 
 IF "%plat%"=="abc" (
  md dir
  copy srt drt
  copy art drt
  copy srt drt
  copy srt drt
 )
 IF "%plat%"=="efg" (
  md dir
  copy srt drt
  copy art drt
  copy srt drt
  copy srt drt
 )
)
rem -------------------------------SiL-----------------------------
IF NOT "%env%"=="S" goto setpython
set cwd=%cd%
set PAR_PATH=Path
cd %PAR_PATH%
set A2L_PATH=path2
for %%i in (*.par) do ccperl perl.pl -a2l=%A2L_PATH%\hn1.a2l -par=%%~ni.par -svl=%%~ni.svl
cd %cwd%
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:setpython
SET SC_DRIVE_LETTER=%CD:~0,2%
SET PATH_SCR_SC=path3
SET PYTHONPATH=python_path

rem ------------------------------PYTHON PARSER----------------------------------------
IF "%env%"=="H" SET testenv=_H
IF "%env%"=="S" SET testenv=

IF %LOAD_XML_FILE%==1 (
 DO something
)

IF %GenAuto%==1 (copy srt drt)
set pyt=python path
for /f %%i in ('call %pyt%') do set gen_output=%%i
SET SKRIPT_PATH=op path
echo Generated files are here: %SKRIPT_PATH%
IF %GenAuto%==1 (
 Do something
)
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


CALL Final.bat
```

and in the mid of code "IF NOT "%env%"=="S" goto setpython", after executing setpython, does it come back and execute rest of the code?
I have problem in understanding until where a function (not sure what is it called in shell script) is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "call" statement in the script is the one at the end, which is used to *temporarily* transfer to the `Final.bat` script.  Otherwise, the script goes top-to-bottom with no loops, no goto's going backward, etc.

As the script executes, it passes the `go_start` label, proceeds down to the line

```
IF NOT "%env%"=="S" goto setpython
```

where it may (depending on the value of the variable `%env%`) proceed to the next line (if it is not `S`) or jump forward to the `setpython` label.  If it proceeds to the next line, it will execute each of the lines until `setpython`.  In either case, once it reaches `setpython`, it continues, executing each line.

There are a few other "if" statements, e.g.,

```
IF %GenAuto%==1 (
    Do something
)
```

where the line

```
Do something
```

may (or may not) be executed, depending on the value of the variable (`%GenAuto%`) which is tested.

For reference: *[Using batch files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx)*

Comment: ok sorry, just eddited my code. please check now. now i have added goto command, while running the :setpython. does it run until call command?

Comment: Still, I see only one "goto" statement.  batch-files can do loops using "goto" (they have no while/do mechanism).

Comment: I actually don't know syntax of shell script, i wanted to know what all is in "gostart" or "set python" is it just the 1st set of statements after those or the entire thing